# How To Cross-Join (Cartesian Product) in Power Query

Tags: powerbi, visualization, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am working in a POWER BI file, and trying to combine two table with any column in common in the QUERY EDITOR. I am trying to do a combinatory of two tables as follow.

Table A:

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |

Table B:

| Column3 |
| --- |
| 2G |
| 4H |

The result desire is:
Table C:

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2G |
| 1 | B | 2G |
| 1 | A | 4H |
| 1 | B | 4H |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do a cross-join, add a custom column to table A as follows:

[image]

[image]

Then expand:

[image]

Comment: Never saw this tricks before :) +1